# batch insert using spark cassandra connector for Scala

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

Im trying to insert some rows into cassandra using a batch statement. I     have not been able to find any documentation on how to do it with the datastax spark connector. I have tried the following

```
CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo({ session =>
    val ps = session.prepare(s"BEGIN BATCH" + 
    "INSERT INTO test.user_trans (user_id, amount) VALUES(?, ?);" +
    "INSERT INTO standing (user_id, position) VALUES (?, ?);" + 
    "APPLY BATCH" );
  val bound = ps.bind(user_id, amount, user_id, position)
  session.execute(bound)
});
```

But the datastax driver gives the following error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:6 mismatched input 'BATCHINSERT' expecting K_BATCH (BEGIN [BATCHINSERT] INTO...)
```

Is it at all possible to do atomic batch update using the datastax spark connector driver?

I'm using the spark-cassandra-connector version 1.6.0-s_2.10
and spark 1.6.1

All other oporations on RDD's and saving single rows to Cassandra works.

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot to put a space after `BEGIN BATCH`

`val ps = session.prepare(s"BEGIN BATCH " + // Put a space after BEGIN BATCH
    "INSERT INTO test.user_trans (user_id, amount) VALUES(?, ?);" +
    "INSERT INTO standing (user_id, position) VALUES (?, ?);" + 
    "APPLY BATCH" );`